# Apply function in R behaving differently

Tags: r

I was studying apply functions in R. Here is what i tried out:

```
> x <- array(1:9,c(3,3))
> x
[,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] 1 4 7
[2,] 2 5 8
[3,] 3 6 9
> apply(x,1,function(x) x * 10)
[,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] 10 20 30
[2,] 40 50 60
[3,] 70 80 90
```

My question is why is it like this? I was thinking, apply will apply the user defined function to each element in the row so that it will look as below. Why does it differ? Is there anything wrong in my understanding.

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] 10    40   70
[2,] 20    50   80
[3,] 30    60   90
```

Comment: `apply` transposes the matrix in when running a function across the rows. For what you are doing, just use `x * 10`. It's an element-wise operator.

Comment: or `apply(x,2,function(x) x * 10)`

Comment: See the first sentence under **Value** in help("apply"). It's difficult to understand but explains this.

Comment: 1 = rows, 2 = columns. Problem? If you want element-wise, use `sapply`.

Comment: Thankyou guys. Actually i was just trying to understand apply function.